# How can I install gitosis on debian wheezy?

Tags: git, debian, gitolite, gitosis

`gitosis` is replaced by `gitolite` in debian wheezy.

But the easiest way for to continue your work after an update would be to just install gitosis from source or a debian packet.

Is this possible on wheezy?

Comment: You might just want to move to gitolite. It's not that hard, and using gitosis makes less and less sense everyday. There is some [doc on doing that](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/migr.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the packet from http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/gitosis

```
cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gitosis/gitosis_0.2+20090917-11_all.deb

#install all dependencies:
apt-get install adduser git-core openssh-server python python-setuptools python-support sudo 

dpkg -i gitosis_0.2+20090917-11_all.deb
```

Comment: Or you can install it from source. The git book has a [chapter on Gitosis](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-7.html).